# Is that possible to use ObjectDB in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, objectdb

I want to use ObjectDB in my Spring Boot application. How should I configure the application.yml file?

I don't want to add persistence.xml into my application. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

with adjustments to ObjectDB, as explained on this forum thread:
http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/860

Comment: I got new error. "Unsupported auto value type java.io.Serializable for field org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable.id" It seems like ObjectDB doesn't support generic ID.