# How to use ObjectDB properly in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, objectdb

I have a spring boot application with objectdb embedded database.

I am manually handling connection and transaction operations as described at http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/overview

Below is a sample code that I am using: (taken from objecdb documentation): 
    `EntityManagerFactory emf =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDbFile.odb");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      // Operations that modify the database should come here.
      em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally {
      if (em.getTransaction().isActive())
          em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }`

It works but the code has become uggly since I had to use try catch finally blocks in order to properly close connections.

I want to refactore my application so that database operations are done in JpaRepositories or Dao classes with @Transactional methods (as described in http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

I had a research on the web but could not find any solution that works.

What I am looking for is a **very simple spring boot sample application** with:

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- Objectdb (embedded)
- Maven
- Uses annotation based configuration (no xml file)
- A dummy entity class (e.g: Customer(id,firstname) )
- A JpaRepository class or dao class with list() and @Transactional persist(Customer) methods

Note: I already tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541865/is-that-possible-to-use-objectdb-in-a-spring-boot-application) but could not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectDB support answered my question

https://www.objectdb.com/forum/2328#item-6